# obtaining the JSON body of a Http request in Salesforce

Tags: ios, json, salesforce, apex-code

I am creating an iOS app with salesforce integration. The iOS app will send JSON data to salesforce in the body of an http request. How do I obtain the body as a JSON string in apex?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (if you were making the callout from within Apex, otherwise use a webservice to capture the incoming call and parse in a similar way).

Prepare your HTTP request object:

```
// Prepare HTTP 
HTTPResponse hTTPRes;
HTTPRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setTimeout(120000);
```

Set your endpoint:

```
req.setEndpoint(baseURL + callName + '?' + parameterString);
```

Make callout:

```
HTTP http = new HTTP();
String body;
hTTPRes = http.send(req);
body = hTTPRes.getBody();
```

Invoke JSON parser and parse your results:

```
// Invoke JSON parser 
JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(body);

// Parse JSON response to get individual field values.
while(parser.nextToken() != null)
{
   if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'yourfield')) 
      // store values as you walk the JSON
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a simple REST webservice in salesforce.com this is quite easy and brings built-in support for JSON or XML messages. Have a look at the following page of the APEX Documentation:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_methods.htm

The complex part of this integration would be the authentication. No matter if you use REST or SOAP you will need a valid session id to authenticate. This could either be done by calling the login operation of the standards Webservice API or using OAuth which would better suit the REST approach but can be quite complicated.
Another integration option especially for iOS development is Simon Fell's zksForce framework which provides a solid way to interact with the standard salesforce.com Webservice API:
[zkSforce at GitHub](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce)

Comment: I have the authentication token all figured out... I just want to put the JSON that is in the body of the request into a string. is there a function i could call that will do this? like:
String jsonString = getBody(); ???

Comment: you need an endpoint to send your request to, so you have to use either the REST or SOAP capabilities of APEX. So you could use something like this: `@RestResource(urlMapping='/myendpoint/*')
global with sharing class MyEndpointClass {

    @HttpPost
    global static Boolean processInput(String input) {
        // process input string here
    }
}`